# Замена символов строки из одного алфавита на символы другого алфавита

Tags: devc++, c, строки, c++

Помогите сделать программу на С.

```
A1 = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J};
A2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Функция заменяет символы строки из одного заданного алфавита на символы другого алфавита

Comment: сами что-нибудь делать пробовали, или хотите, чтобы все сделали за вас?

Comment: Ну... найти элемент в первом массиве, подставить вместо него элемент второго с таким же номером...

Comment: @Zelta, попробуйте разобраться в [этом](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/) и [этом](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) примерах.

Или сами какой-нибудь "ассоциативный массив"  на Си напишите.

Comment: @avp ну Вы уж так-то не пугайте. Для восьмибитных символов таблица перекодировки

     char a1a2[256];
     bzero(a1a2, 256);
     for(i=0; i<sizeof A1; i++) a1a2[A1[i]] = A2[i];
     a1a2[' '] = ' ';
     a1a2['\n'] = '\n';

А Вы ассоциативными массивами пугаете.

PS: только при перекодировании не забывать про знак, `a1a2[(unsigned char) c]`

Comment: Конечно, пугаю, предупреждая шок от Unicode (более конкретно от русских букв в UTF-8).

А для побайтовой замены IMHO лучше вместо `bzero()` инициализировать самими кодами:

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) a1a2[i] = i;
    for(i=0; i<sizeof A1; i++) a1a2[A1[i]] = A2[i];

тогда дальнейший код по перекодировке будет совсем тривиальным.

Comment: @avp ну тогда определение отсутствующих в алфавите символов придётся определять по совпадению символа заменяемого с заменяющим. Мне это не нравится (т.е. серьёзных возражений нет, но не нравится)

Хотя, моё желание сохранять пробелы становится более сложно реализуемым.

Comment: @alexlz, ну в условиях задачи просто не определено, что делать с другими символами.

Один подход - просто не менять. Другой - заменить на что-то (например, у Вас на 0).

Answer (score 2):

[[@atticus](/users/12943/atticus)](/users/12943/atticus) так?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string s;
  while(!cin.eof()) {
    cin >> s;
    for(string::iterator it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); it++) {
        if(*it < 'A' || *it > 'J') {
            cout << "Неверный символ " << *it << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        *it -= 'A' - '0';
    }
    cout << s;
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да все верно.Большое спасибо.

Comment: @atticus это была шутка. Во-первых, нет никаких массивов (по условиям задачи вроде должны быть). Второе -- отношение программы к пробелам/переводам строки (они отбрасываются).

Comment: @alexlz: А почему шутка? Хороший оптимизирующий компилятор вполне мог бы поиск по массиву превратить в такой код, как у вас. (развернуть цикл прохода по массиву -> подставить константы -> сделать таблицу значений -> схлопнуть её в выражение)

Comment: Вспомним Станиславского и его любимую фразу "Не верю!"

Comment: Почему не верите? Знаете историю про оптимизирующий компилятор, который выкинул все вычисления, поскольку результирующее значение данные программой не выводились?

Comment: @VladD что значит "историю"? Нормальное поведение нормального оптимизатора. Правда году в 94м-95м оно несколько удивило (watcom c 9.5), но это -- нормально. А вот замена поиска на другой алгоритм -- эт' вряд ли.

Comment: @alexlz: я же даже в скобках расписал последовательность оптимизаций.

Comment: @VladD, а вот в это верю!

Просто такая оптимизация тривиальна (выявляется на этапе оптимизации распределения памяти) и поэтому осуществлена, а вот предыдущая один из тысяч возможных вариантов (тысяч, конечно, для всех вообразимых "мелких" алгоритмов, а не только этой задачи). 

Возможно, когда-нибудь, с развитием AI (т.е. когда компилятор будет *понимать* задачу, которую реализует программа (другой вопрос, а зачем тогда такую программу писать?)) такие штуки станут осуществимыми.

Comment: Ну, смотрите.

1. `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) if (x == a[i]) return b[i]` -> `if (x == a[0]) return b[0]; if (x == a[1]) return b[1]; ...`
2. `if (x == a[0])` -> `if (x == 'A')`
3. Последовательность `if`'ов -> switch
4. Сворачиваем range в switch (дефолтная оптимизация в Java, например): `if (arg outside range) default; else jump table[arg]`
5. инлайним case'ы
6. выносим общее подвыражение за jump
7. видим, что теперь все случаи одинаковые, и схлопываем их.

Comment: @VladD, да, очень похоже. Пожалуй, я был не прав.

Comment: @VladD присоединяюсь к @avp. Увы.